# If given Differential equation ordinary or partial?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Is x^2 dy + y^2 dx = 0 ordinary or partial?  Also if linear or non-linear?

Comment: You can write it in the form $$ x^2 \frac{dy}{dx} + y^2 = 0 $$, which is an ordinary type of differential equation.

Comment: Thanks i got it Matti P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dividing by $x^2y^2$,

$$\frac{dy}{y^2}+\frac{dx}{x^2}=0,$$ and after integration

$$-\frac1y-\frac1x=C$$ or

$$y=\frac x{Cx-1}.$$

This is a first order, non-linear, separable ODE.

$$y=0$$ is also a solution.